# Adding a new layer of roads to google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm working on a project to build a geo-location based information system for an institute and i'm supossed to use google maps API as a part for that. In this system we have to specify all possible roads and paths which are inside the institute(which are not visible as roads in google maps).
Is there any way to add new road layer (which has all features same as roads already marked on google maps)to my maps in google maps??

Comment: Check the link might be help full. [https://www.google.com/maps/about/partners/indoormaps/](https://www.google.com/maps/about/partners/indoormaps/)